# Allow properties from an object, excluding its parents

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

We need to allow only certains parameters in a function, theses parameters come from a child class, and must exclude its parents properties.

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsBrgIzQBc0EALgE4EB2A5hgLzQDkn6WehxXACZK0RtgC2uBHWgcADL0xNmACgCUlAG4B7AgBMUAX1QnUoSDADCACwIhDCAB40EjfTHgQkaDDnxEGMDkVLQMLHJcPH78gdDAIlTiUjKRihjeNPEAzNCqWmAg2EhJktKymsjQJn46LBqiugbIJmY0AJ6YSADyjCDttvaGHN0SBDQAPIMOADTQANYI7ToAZnCIAHzQAGQo0ADaANLQTAtLq+veALpJCFqpZivYjMA0BHXQrrSqWHQ6mDAqL1+tNDJoqE1DGgAPTQ6AAOkR8NMqFQXxoql88RCXGAnDmCVEpDmsOghRAOgA7gh9LwyJROLh8dBhKIhCS4TI-nRUUFslQAERcnR0AUc6DCuhzCA2HTYBwspBgMRlGSmdRAA)

```js
class Base {
  public  b1 : string  = ''
  public b2 : number = 0
  ping() :void {}
}

class Child extends Base {
  public  c1 : string = ''
  public  c2 : number = 0
  set c3 (value : number ) { }
  pong() : void{}
}
```

For now, this seems to work, but it allow all props, including parent props.

```js
function test<T>( props : Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, string>> ) : void {void {
// ....
}
```

```js
test<Child>({
  c1 : '', c2 : 1, // allowed
  b1 :'', b2 : 2, // error

  c3: "error", // error, should be a number
})
```

Bonus: Is it possible to only allow props that have a `setter` or a public prop and exclude functions of `Child` ?

Comment: This is a bit closer: https://tsplay.dev/wj5Y8W. Not entirely sure why I had to `& { [K in keyof Base]: never }` though.

Comment: The interface for `Child` does not encode any information about which properties are inherited and which are not, so I don't see a way of doing this that doesn't look like `test<Child, Base>(...)`.  Are you interested in such a solution?  Or do you just an explanation for why what you are asking for is not directly possible?

Comment: @jcalz So the `Base` classe(s) contains all helper methods, and the `Child` only contains getter/setters. Our end goal is to filter everything that is not a setter or a public prop.

Comment: In your example, `Base` does not have helper methods; it has `string` and `number` properties.  Could you modify your code to constitute a [mcve] of the actual issue you're trying to solve?  It is definitely possible to filter properties to include only non-function-valued properties, but that wouldn't work with the question as stated.

Comment: @jcalz Updated.